# TypeScript Optional properties break type enforcement for function arguments

Tags: typescript

I expect the type checker to print an error for the below example. Is this a bug or by design? Note, that if you remove the `?`, you will get the error, as one would expect.

```
type Right = { right?: boolean }
type Wrong = { wrong: number }

function returnWrong(callback: (param: Right) => Right) { }

returnWrong((param: Wrong) => param.wrong) // should fail but doesn't
```

Both the parameter and return types differ from declared in the invocation, but the compiler doesn't seem to catch it.

I have strictNullChecks and noImplicitAny enabled.

Here is a more elaborate example, which type checks OK but throws a runtime error.

```
function returnWrongX(p: Right, callback: (param: Right) => Right) { 
 return callback(p).right
}
returnWrongX({}, (param: Wrong) =>
    param.wrong)
```

Edit:
Saravana suggested adding `& object` as a workaround. That works for the above, but there remains a possibility to further elaborate the example by nesting the `Wrong` object:

```
type Right = { right?: boolean } & object // added `& object`
type Wrong = { wrong: {fail: number} } // Wrong.wrong is now an object

function returnWrongX(p: Right, callback: (param: Right) => Right) { 
    return callback(p).right
}
// `param` is expecting a `Wrong` but receiving a `Right`
// so it throws a runtime error 
returnWrongX({}, (param: Wrong) => param.wrong.fail ? {} : {})
```

Comment: Found this [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html), there is a section on `Optional Parameters in Callbacks`, might be useful

Comment: I'm not seeing how it relates, but thanks.

Comment: Idea is that when having only optional fields in your type, this type becomes something like `any`, thus why it's ok to replace it with any other type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). So based on your definition for `Right`, all possible values for `Wrong` are compatible with `Right`:

```
let objw: Wrong = {
    wrong: 1
}

let objr: Right = objw; // No error
```

And any value of type `Wrong` is guaranteed to be at-least an object `{wrong: number}` which satisfies the requirement for `Right` which accepts anything including `number` (`let num: Right = 55;` works) the return type from callback. Which is why the compiler does not throw any error.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't it be the reverse? Since `param` of type `Wrong` is being assigned a value of type `Right`? Something like this seems to be the case, `let right: Right = { right: true }; let param: Wrong = right;`. Or am I getting lost in contravariances?

Comment: You cannot assign `right` to `param` in your example because `right` is missing the mandatory `wrong` property required by `Wrong` type. Whereas `Right` defines no mandatory property. Which is why anything goes as `Right`.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the second example: the same thing happens in the original code with the callback. Take a look at the new edit that elaborates on this idea. This time it throws an exception when ran. It seems to me that the type checker should be catching this.

Comment: Yes. That is something the compiler should catch. I think the question now is why `let num: Right = 55;` is valid since that is allowing you to return a number from callback. Perhaps file a bug at the [official repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7485) seems to be related to this. As a workaround you can do `type Right = { right?: boolean } & object`

Comment: Good find, thanks! This seems to now type check the return value, but still not the parameters. I've updated the question with a further elaboration.